# Writing test class for constructor

Tags: apex, unit-test, constructor

like title says ,I'm trying to write a test class for the following constructor , but I'm getting Constructor not defined error. My method is :

```
public class AccountPlanSumLightningController {
 public class tmpOIResultNode {

        public Decimal x;
        
        public Decimal y;
        
        public String hoverText;
        
        public String currencyCode;

        tmpOIResultNode (Decimal ACNAbilityToImpact, Decimal PotentialValue, String hoverText, String 
          currCode) {
            this.x = ACNAbilityToImpact;
            this.y = PotentialValue;
            this.hoverText = hoverText;
            this.currencyCode = currCode;
        }
    }
}
```

I was trying tu use in

```
AccountPlanSumLightningController.tmpOIResultNode testOI = new AccountPlanSumLightningController.tmpOIResultNode(0.10,0.20,'test','010');
```

in test method , but didn't work, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor is `private`, the default access level for classes, methods, and properties, so you cannot call it outside the class. Add `@TestVisible` or make the constructor `public`.

```
    public tmpOIResultNode (Decimal ACNAbilityToImpact, Decimal PotentialValue, String hoverText, String
```

Or

```
    @TestVisible tmpOIResultNode (Decimal ACNAbilityToImpact, Decimal PotentialValue, String hoverText, String
```

Comment: Thanks!! that worked out!